# Extra data in result for AES/GCM decryption

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, crypto++

I have the following code, basically grabbed right from the Crypto++ wiki at http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter

The problem is, with the output I get "plaintext: abc1230000000077C8E390" instead of what I'd expect, just "plaintext: abc123"

What is the extra data at the end?

Also- two more small questions that are based on the same codebase:

1. would this method serve as a drop-in replacement for using actual random byte data for pdata- or since it's string must it actually be like usual text?
2. I assume adata is meant to be transferred in plaintext, so when storing the ciphertext, am I correct that both the iv and adata are in plaintext, and the user only provides the key (to decrypt the ciphertext with those 4 elements: key (provided by user), ciphertext (made available), iv (made available), and adata (made available)?

Thank you!

```
AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

byte key[ AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ];
prng.GenerateBlock( key, sizeof(key) );

byte iv[ AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
prng.GenerateBlock( iv, sizeof(iv) );

string adata( 16, (char)0x00 );

string cipherText = encryptData("abc123", adata, key, iv);
string plainText = decryptData(cipherText, adata, key, iv);
cout << "plaintext: " << plainText << endl;

//Utilities
string MainWindow::encryptData(string pdata, string adata, const byte *key, const byte *iv) {
    const int TAG_SIZE = 16;

    string cipher;

    try
        {
            GCM< AES >::Encryption e;
            e.SetKeyWithIV( key, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, iv, AES::BLOCKSIZE );

            AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter ef( e,
                new StringSink( cipher ), false, TAG_SIZE
            ); // AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter

            ef.ChannelPut( "AAD", (const byte*)adata.data(), adata.size() );
            ef.ChannelMessageEnd("AAD");

            ef.ChannelPut( "", (const byte*)pdata.data(), pdata.size() );
            ef.ChannelMessageEnd("");
        }
        catch( CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::NoChannelSupport& e )
        {
            cerr << "Caught NoChannelSupport..." << endl;
            cerr << e.what() << endl;
            cerr << endl;
        }
        catch( CryptoPP::AuthenticatedSymmetricCipher::BadState& e )
        {
            cerr << "Caught BadState..." << endl;
            cerr << e.what() << endl;
            cerr << endl;
        }
        catch( CryptoPP::InvalidArgument& e )
        {
            cerr << "Caught InvalidArgument..." << endl;
            cerr << e.what() << endl;
            cerr << endl;
        }

    return(cipher);
}

string MainWindow::decryptData(string cipher, string adata, const byte *key, const byte *iv) {
    const int TAG_SIZE = 16;
    string radata, rpdata;
    try
    {
        GCM< AES >::Decryption d;
        d.SetKeyWithIV( key, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH, iv, AES::BLOCKSIZE );

        string enc = cipher.substr( 0, cipher.length()-TAG_SIZE );
        string mac = cipher.substr( cipher.length()-TAG_SIZE );

        assert( cipher.size() == enc.size() + mac.size() );
        assert( enc.size() == pdata.size() );
        assert( TAG_SIZE == mac.size() );

        radata = adata;

        AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter df( d, NULL,
            AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::MAC_AT_BEGIN |
            AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION, TAG_SIZE );

        df.ChannelPut( "", (const byte*)mac.data(), mac.size() );
        df.ChannelPut( "AAD", (const byte*)adata.data(), adata.size() );
        df.ChannelPut( "", (const byte*)enc.data(), enc.size() );

        df.ChannelMessageEnd( "AAD" );
        df.ChannelMessageEnd( "" );

        string retrieved;
        size_t n = (size_t)df.MaxRetrievable();
        retrieved.resize( n );

        if( n > 0 ) { df.Get( (byte*)retrieved.data(), n ); }
        rpdata = retrieved;
        assert( rpdata == pdata );

    }
    catch( CryptoPP::InvalidArgument& e )
    {
        cerr << "Caught InvalidArgument..." << endl;
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        cerr << endl;
    }
    catch( CryptoPP::AuthenticatedSymmetricCipher::BadState& e )
    {
        cerr << "Caught BadState..." << endl;
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        cerr << endl;
    }
    catch( CryptoPP::HashVerificationFilter::HashVerificationFailed& e )
    {
        cerr << "Caught HashVerificationFailed..." << endl;
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
        cerr << endl;
    }

    return rpdata;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is, with the output I get "plaintext: abc1230000000077C8E390"

My guess here is you reused a string. Crypto++ will append, and not overwrite, in a `StringSink`. So you got `abc123`, and then you managed to append `0000000077C8E390` somehow.

---

The following works for me. Its a mildly modified version of your program. It makes `adata` and `pdata` global, renames them to avoid name hiding, and passes the message through `pdata`.

```
$ ./cryptopp-test.exe
plaintext: Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country

$ ./cryptopp-test.exe wxyz
plaintext: wxyz
```

---

Because you are using `THROW_EXCEPTION`, you don't need this:

```c++
b = df.GetLastResult();
assert( true == b );
```

---

> I assume adata is meant to be transferred in plaintext...

Yes. It would be something like an IP address, a disk sector or counter (among others).

More correctly, its data that is authenticated only. If its tampered with, it will be detected.

---

> ... am I correct that both the iv and adata are in plaintext

The IV can be a public or private parameter.

If its a public parameter, then it does not need to be authenticated. Its a little non-intuitive, but that's because tampering with the IV will tamper with the cipher's state, so decryption will fail as if you used the wrong key.

---

> ... the user only provides the key (to decrypt the ciphertext with those 4 elements: key (provided by user), ciphertext (made available), iv (made available), and adata (made available)?

The `pdata` gets confidentiality and authenticity assurances; and `adata` gets authenticity assurances only.

The key and IV are customary. Handle them like you always do (or should do :).

---

```c++
using CryptoPP::DEFAULT_CHANNEL;
using CryptoPP::AAD_CHANNEL;

string encryptData(const string& pdata, const string& adata, const byte *key, unsigned int ksize, const byte *iv, unsigned int vsize);
string decryptData(const string& cipher, const string& adata, const byte *key, unsigned int ksize, const byte *iv, unsigned int vsize);

string xadata = "172.16.1.10";
string xpdata = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country";

static const unsigned int TAG_SIZE = 16;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    (void)argc; (void)argv;

    if(argc >= 2)
        xpdata = argv[1];

    try {

        AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

        byte key[ AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH ];
        prng.GenerateBlock( key, sizeof(key) );

        byte iv[ AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
        prng.GenerateBlock( iv, sizeof(iv) );

        string cipherText = encryptData(xpdata, xadata, key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));
        string plainText = decryptData(cipherText, xadata, key, sizeof(key), iv, sizeof(iv));

        cout << "plaintext: " << plainText << endl;
    }
    catch(CryptoPP::Exception& ex)
    {
        cerr << ex.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

//Utilities
string encryptData(const string& pdata, const string& adata, const byte *key, unsigned int ksize, const byte *iv, unsigned int vsize) {

    string cipher;

    GCM< AES >::Encryption e;
    e.SetKeyWithIV( key, ksize, iv, vsize );

    AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter ef( e,
                                     new StringSink( cipher ), false, TAG_SIZE
                                     ); // AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter

    ef.ChannelPut(AAD_CHANNEL, (const byte*)adata.data(), adata.size() );
    ef.ChannelMessageEnd(AAD_CHANNEL);

    ef.ChannelPut(DEFAULT_CHANNEL, (const byte*)pdata.data(), pdata.size() );
    ef.ChannelMessageEnd(DEFAULT_CHANNEL);

    return(cipher);
}

string decryptData(const string& cipher, const string& adata, const byte *key, unsigned int ksize, const byte *iv, unsigned int vsize) {

    string recovered;

    GCM< AES >::Decryption d;
    d.SetKeyWithIV( key, ksize, iv, vsize );

    const string& enc = cipher.substr( 0, cipher.length()-TAG_SIZE );
    const string& mac = cipher.substr( cipher.length()-TAG_SIZE );

    assert( cipher.size() == enc.size() + mac.size() );
    assert( enc.size() == xpdata.size() );
    assert( TAG_SIZE == mac.size() );

    AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter df( d, new StringSink(recovered),
                                     AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::MAC_AT_BEGIN |
                                     AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION, TAG_SIZE );

    df.ChannelPut(DEFAULT_CHANNEL, (const byte*)mac.data(), mac.size() );
    df.ChannelPut(AAD_CHANNEL, (const byte*)adata.data(), adata.size() );
    df.ChannelPut(DEFAULT_CHANNEL, (const byte*)enc.data(), enc.size() );

    df.ChannelMessageEnd(AAD_CHANNEL);
    df.ChannelMessageEnd(DEFAULT_CHANNEL);

    assert( recovered == xpdata );        
    return(recovered);
}
```

Comment: So it turns out my actual bug was not having "using std::endl" - so << endl was giving me weird stuff :) - but this was incredibly informative and you answered my sub-questions, thanks!

Comment: @David - a win is a win :) Since you are using [Authenticated Encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption), you understand the need for things like confidentiality and authenticity. Your next step, which provides even more security under weaker conditions, is an [Integrated Encryption System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme). For that, check out [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme).